# Passing extra data from an Activity to an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am calling an `Activity` using an `Intent`, and I need to pass variables to that `Activity` when is initialized. On iOS you can use a custom initialization using the `initWithNibName` method. How can a similar thing be achieved on Android?

Here is my code that creates an `Intent`...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(webPush.this, webPushActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(webPush.this, webPushActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("mystring",strValue)' <<---put String here 
startActivity(myIntent);
```

and in second Activity...

```
String str = getIntent.getExtras().getString("mystring");<<get string in second class
```

and check this

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can put extra data into the Intent...

```
myIntent.putExtra("exampleString","This is some extra data");
myIntent.putExtra("exampleNumber",1234);
```

When you call the `Intent`, it starts the `Activity`. in one of the main methods of the `Activity`, like `onCreate()`, you can access the `Intent` and get the extras from it, like so...

```
Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
String exampleString = callingIntent.getStringExtra("exampleString");
int exampleNumber = callingIntent.getIntExtra("exampleNumber");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set extras to the intent:

```
myIntent.putStringExtra("First key", 1);
myIntent.putStringExtra("Second key", "some string");
```

And then get it in the new activity

```
Int extraInt = getIntent().getIntExtra("First key");    
String extraString = getIntent().getStringExtra("Second key");
```

See more in the [Intent docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with intent extras. For example:

```
int variable = 6;
Intent myIntent = new Intent(webPush.this, webPushActivity.class);
myIntent.PutExtra("stringLabel", variable);
startActivity(myIntent);
```